# display hyperlink in Vaadin Grid

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I'm trying to display a HTML link in a Vaadin grid column.

I have the following code:

```java
Grid<DetailInfoRow> grid = new Grid<>();
grid.addColumn(LitRenderer.<DetailInfoRow> of("<span>${item.name}</span>").withProperty("name", DetailInfoRow::getName)).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.START);
grid.addColumn(LitRenderer.<DetailInfoRow> of("<span>${item.value}</span>").withProperty("value", DetailInfoRow::getValue)).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.START);
grid.setSelectionMode(Grid.SelectionMode.NONE);
grid.setAllRowsVisible(true);
```

The `value` field of `DetailInfoRow` is of `String` type, and sometimes has a value like `"<a href="http://10.1.194.60:8888/update">10.1.194.60</a>"`.
But in browser it is rendered as literal and not interpreted as a link to external resource. I thought that's what `LitRenderer` could do.

What's wrong with the above code, please? Thank you.

Comment: Lit can only render unsafe HTML, when you call the `unsafeHTML` function
around it.  If there are really just links, I'd rather parse/transform
them beforehand.

Comment: @cfrick Thank you! Your hint led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302820/dynamic-html-using-a-vaadin-litrenderer/71319132#71319132 and I changed to using ComponentRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in [Dynamic HTML using a Vaadin LitRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71302820/dynamic-html-using-a-vaadin-litrenderer/71319132#71319132).

I chose to go with `ComponentRenderer` to render unsafe HTML:

```java
grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(info -> new Html(String.format("<span>%s</span>", info.getValue())))).setTextAlign(ColumnTextAlign.START);
```